# Julia 1.1.1 - absolutely global variables

Tags: julia

I am coming from Fortran and I use global vectors of data over the full program. Usually I declare a module:

```
module xyz   
     real, allocatable :: vector(:,:,:)   ! a 3 dim vector, undefined    
end module
```

Now, in some place, let say Subroutine (Function) A, I am allocating memory for it and initialize to some values:

```
allocate(vector(10,20,30))    
vector = ran()
```

Now, in any other unit of the program (Subroutine or function B, C, D...), if I am using the module, i.e:

```
using xyz
```

The above declared vector is available.

I was not able to obtain this behavior in the new technological wonder Julia 1.1. The scope rules are just giving a headache.

Comment: Please let me know if the explanation is clear; if not I can expand on it.

Comment: Be mindful that there are [several reasons to avoid using global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad), so you might want to explore a different approach.

Comment: Bogumil -- Thanks for your help. Reading documentation and doing with your hands is different. I figured out that I need both export and global in the defining module, in order to make the variable generally available.

Answer (score 4):

In Julia the rules for accessing variables from other modules are explained in detail [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/modules/).

The key issues in your situation are the following things:

- a variable is visible after `using` only if it is `export`ed in the module
- you are allowed to access the variable in other modules
- you are not allowed to rebind a variable from other modules

This means that global variable binding creation operation is private to the module.

Here is a simple example module definition:

```
module M

export x

x = Int[]

function rebindx()
    global x = Int[]
end

end
```

now assume you define and later use it in REPL (it could be any other module)

```
julia> module M

       export x

       x = Int[]

       function rebindx()
           global x = Int[]
       end

       end
Main.M

julia> using .M
```

Now you can access `x`:

```
julia> x
0-element Array{Int64,1}

julia> push!(x, 1)
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1

julia> x
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1

julia> x[1] = 10
10

julia> x
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 10
```

But not rebind `x`:

```
julia> x = 0
ERROR: cannot assign variable M.x from module Main
```

However, you can call a function defined inside `M` module to change the binding of `x` like this:

```
julia> x
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 10

julia> M.rebindx()
0-element Array{Int64,1}

julia> x
0-element Array{Int64,1}
```

This was possible because `rebindx` was defined inside module `M` so it has the right to change the binding of variable `x` defined in this module.